# Difference betwen dates is wrong

Tags: flutter

The result of this

```
nextEventDuration = nextRace.raceTime.difference(nowTime); 
print(nextRace.raceTime.toIso8601String() + " " +  nowTime.toIso8601String() + " " + nextEventDuration.inHours.toString());
```

is

```
2021-03-28T17:00:00.000 2021-03-27T17:00:00.000 23
```

It should be 24 right?

Comment: Add as least all code for make local example and explain more your problem

Comment: Might be because many countries switch to summertime on Sunday 28 March 02:00. So 23 might be correct depending on your locale

Comment: Yes @MTilsted this is the reason, I've figured it out later

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's 24 hours, it should be 23:59:59:999.
What is the result of `nextEventDuration.toString()` in seconds?